# how can I create class objects using a list?

Tags: python

This is my class program, for the instances I've created so far, it's worked fine.

```
from random import random

class team:
    wins = 0
    losses = 0

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def win(self):
        self.wins += 1

    def lose(self):
        self.losses += 1

    def play(self,opponent):
        if random()<0.5:
            self.win()
            opponent.lose()
            print(self.name,"won",opponent.name,"lost")
        else:
            self.lose()
            opponent.win()
            print(opponent.name,"won",self.name,"lost")
            

    def record(self):
        return (self.wins,'-',self.losses)

    def startgames(self, array_of_team_objects):
        k = 1
        outer = 0
        space = True
        while outer<len(array_of_team_objects):
            inner = 0
            while space == True:
                inner = outer + k
                if inner == len(Teams): space = False
                array_of_team_objects[outer].play(array_of_team_objects[inner])
                k +=1
            #whileinner
            outer+=1
        #whileouter
        print("Every team has now played every other team once")
        
 
team1 = team("Yankees") # creates a team object with given name
team2 = team("Mets")    # each new team starts with 0 wins and 0 losses
team1.play(team2)  #prints "Yankees won, Mets lost" or "Mets won, Yankees lost"
print(team1.record()) # should print "1-0" or "0-1" depending on above
print(team2.record()) # should print "0-1" or "1-0" depending on above
```

For the next part of this program, which I will use the 'startgames' method for, I want to make every element of the list 'Names' an object of the class. How can I do this?

```
Names =["Mets","Yankees","Dodgers","Cubs","Nationals","Rays","Marlins","Braves","Twins","Athletics","Orioles","Royals","Phillies","Pirates"]
```

Comment: `teams = list(map(team, Names))`

Comment: Off-topic: You should make `wins` and `losses` *instance* attributes, not class attributes as you have them now — because otherwise their values will be shared among *all* the instances of the class. To do this create them in the `__init__()` method, not where you have them now.